# Is there any StackNotify extension for `Safari` browser?

Tags: support, safari, addon

Is there any StackNotify extension for Safari browser? I have Google Chrome version which is good. Looking for an Safari version?

[image: appforgrhrome]

Comment: Half-unrelated: Can I have a link to that notifier for Chrome please? C:

Comment: Its a chrome extension i have added to my browser,and it is working fine! [chrome-Addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknotify/jekfdfagmfmibhidlkkecfchoghlldak)

Comment: You should post a feature request at the [Stack app listing of StackNotify](http://stackapps.com/questions/2356/stacknotify-google-chrome-extension). Or write the extension yourself, here's the documentation for Safari extensions: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the chrome extension link.. It works beautifully..

Comment: May I have some up vote? :) people who got benefit from the chrome extension?